# How did we discover that this quadratic residue oriented PRNG generates unique numbers in a sequence?

Tags: permutations, cryptography, random, quadratic-residues

### Question (tl;dr)

How do we know that even for extremely large numbers like even far past $32^{15}$ (any bigint, or any number really), that as you increment the sequence from $0$ to $n$, $n$ being the max, that every output as a result of `permute(i)` (defined below), for every `i` up to `n`, will be unique? How do we know that? Who discovered it? *(not necessary for the answer to know exactly who discovered it, but it would be a bonus to know!)*

To me the only way to show this would be to check the output of `permute(i)` has no duplicates running through every possible input (up to n). But how do we know how it works without doing that? How did anyone ever figure this out? *(When, roughly speaking, was this even discovered)?*

### Background

There is a "[quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) oriented" PRNG "magic" function (to me it's magic), described [here](https://preshing.com/20121224/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-unique-random-integers/), an example of which is found below, which I got from asking [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65855154/how-to-get-this-prng-to-generate-numbers-within-the-range) and made into a [JavaScript library](https://github.com/lancejpollard/quadratic-residue-prng.js). It can be implemented in just 2 lines of code (or [10](https://github.com/lancejpollard/quadratic-residue-prng.js/blob/make/index.js)):

```
const rotate = (x, o) => x >= o ? x : (x <= (o / 2n)) ? ((x * x) % o) : o - ((x * x) % o)
const permute = (v, w, s, x, m) => rotate((rotate(v, w) + s) % m ^ x, w)
```

*Sidenote: I don't know if I am [naming these functions correctly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4354689/what-are-these-permutation-quadratic-residue-prng-functions-called), I just called them what seemed appropriate.*

An example of how it is used is like this:

```
const E = 3132343537383103113163n
const A = 975319753197531975319n
const O = 541613713n
const U = 32 ** 15

let i = 0
while (i < U) {
  const x = permute(i, E, A, O, U)
  console.log(x)
  i++
}
```

*More description is in the [repo description](https://github.com/lancejpollard/quadratic-residue-prng.js#readme), on why we chose specific primes and a use case for this function.*

Now, the only information I have on how this works comes from that [blog linked above](https://preshing.com/20121224/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-unique-random-integers/), which is copied here:

---

[image]

---

### Conclusion

How is this even possible? Seemingly random numbers jumping around an enormous sequence, fill in the slots without ever encountering a duplicate?! That is so crazy to me. Hence the main question.

Comment: [+1] Very interesting. Unfortunately not in my range of expertise...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the linked blog explains, as long as each operation you do just shuffles the integers around, you'll never get duplicates. You can do as many shuffles of a pack of cards as you like, you'll never get duplicate cards appear when you deal them out later.

Shuffle operations on a finite set are also called permutations. They are invertible - any shuffle could be undone by the appropriate unshuffling operation.

The three shuffling operations used here are:

- addition of $s$ modulo $m$
- xor-ing with x
- the operation which you call "rotate"

The first two are permutations of $0$...$m-1$ because they are easily invertible (assuming $m$ is a power of $2$). It is much trickier to see why the third operation is a permutation. Note that this third operation works if $w$ is a prime which satisfies $w\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ but not necessarily in other cases.

There are a few steps needed to prove this.

1. The non-zero squares mod $p$ cover exactly half of the numbers $1$,...,$p-1$.

**Proof:** The numbers $1^2$,...,$(p-1)^2$ cover at most half the numbers cause every number is duplicated due to the fact that $x^2=(-x)^2$. However, there can't be further duplicates:

$$x^2\equiv y^2 \pmod p \\ x^2-y^2\equiv 0 \pmod p \\ (x-y)(x+y)\equiv 0 \pmod p \\ x-y\equiv 0 \pmod p \text{ or } x+y\equiv 0 \pmod p \\ x\equiv y \pmod p \text{ or } x\equiv -y \pmod p$$

Note that we used the fact that $p$ is a prime in the step to the second to last line, using the fact that if a prime divides a product, then the prime must divide one of the factors.

2. If $-1$ is not a square mod $p$, then the squares and the negated squares cover all of the numbers $1$,...,$p-1$.

**Proof:** A non-zero square cannot equal a negated square, because if $x^2\equiv -y^2 \pmod p$ then $(xy^{-1})^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$, making $-1$ a square contrary to our assumption. This shows that the non-zero squares and negated squares don't overlap. They each cover half the numbers, so together they cover all the numbers.

Putting this together, you see that the squares of $1$,...$(p-1)/2$ and the negated squares of the rest cover all the non-zero numbers mod $p$. Combined with mapping $0$ to $0$, you get a permutation of the first $p$ integers. We do need $p$ to be a prime such that $-1$ is not a square modulo $p$. This is the case when $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$, which can be shown using [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion).

**Addendum:**
Although this "rotate" operation is a permutation of the numbers $0$ to $p-1$, and therefore invertible, it is not easy to invert when $p$ is large. Suppose the result of the operation is $r$, and the input we want to find is $x$. It is relatively easy to check whether $r$ is a square mod $p$ using [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity). If $r$ is a square, then $x=\sqrt{r} \pmod p$, and otherwise $x=-\sqrt{-r} \pmod p$. The hard part is taking that square root mod $p$, but there are algorithms for that such as the [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) algorithm.

Comment: Wow this is intense, way over my head :) I will have to study this for a long time. Any possibility that more explanation can be added to uncover some of the implicit assumptions and implicit solutions? I am excited by the idea of potentially being able to explain this to others, but first I need to understand exactly what you mean :) In particular, I still don't see the inner details of how it randomly jumps about yet never introduces a duplicate. Amongst other things.

Comment: Also, how would you undo this function, that would be really interesting to know! I think I asked that somewhere else I can't remember, but I think no one thought it was possible.

Comment: @Lance I've added some links to explain how to invert this function, but it is complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much, this at least points me into the right direction, I appreciate it!